# Calling GameScene in another Class with parameter in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skscene

I am so frustrated trying to get this working for 2 hours now!!!

I have two classes `GameScene` and `Setup` and I want to print the frame of `GameScene` in my `Setup` class.

```
class Setup {

   static var gameScene = GameScene()
   static func whatsFrame() {
      print("\(gameScene.frame.maxX)")
}


class GameScene: SKScene {

   override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
      print("\(self.frame.maxX)")
      Setup.whatsFrame()
   }
}
```

It should be so simple but the console gives following answer:

```
320.0 and -0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing `GameScene` frame-information via parameters to your `Setup` class like:

In your `GameScene` `didMove()` function:

```
        Setup.whatsFrame(frameOfGameSceneMaxX: self.frame.maxX,
                            frameOfGameSceneMinX: self.frame.minX)
```

And in your `Setup` class:

```
   static func whatsFrame(frameOfGameSceneMaxX: CGFloat, frameOfGameSceneMinX: CGFloat) {
       print("\(frameOfGameSceneMaxX)")
       print("\(frameOfGameSceneMinX)")
}
```